# MongoDB NodeJS always expiring after one minute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timezone, momentjs, utc

I am using the [MongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) npm module in my node app and I have this code to create a new object in the collection with a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/):

```
var utcDate = new Date();
var emailObj = {email: emailAddress, createdAt: utcDate};
dbo.collection("initialEmail").createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 });
dbo.collection("initialEmail").insertOne(emailObj, function(err, response) {
    ...
});
```

However, the entry always deletes after about one minute (instead of the 1 hour I set it to be).

I got from my research that mongo runs its script to delete about every [one minute](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation). This makes me think that for some reason my mongo server timezone is off from my node server timezone, therefore making the mongo expiration time of the object created already an hour before the current mongo server time.

For the `utcDate` variable, I have tried:

- `new Date( moment.utc().format() );`
- `new Date( moment().valueOf() );`
- `new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);`

But there was no effect. All of these make the object delete after about 1 minute.

I have also tried: (for `utcDate`)

- `moment().valueOf();`
- `Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;`

But these cause the type of `createdAt` when viewing the object as JSON to be an int, and the object never gets deleted, (even after waiting many minutes after expected expiration).

How can I ensure the object inserted will always last at least an hour?

Answer (score 1):

I am using docker-compose, with the official [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) image. I switched back to `var utcDate = new Date();`, and guessed maybe somehow the docker image saved the index for some reason from when, a long time ago, I set the `expireAfterSeconds` value to 60. And because it does not "[change the value of expireAfterSeconds of an existing index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#restrictions)," my value must have still been 60.

I deleted the image and ran `docker-compose up` again and it worked.

I am not using docker volumes at all, so I thought the mongo image would be a completely fresh build each and every time. I do not fully understand the semi-persistence of data in Docker images, so if you understand why the database collection index properties were saved from one `up` to another, please comment and educate me.